# Nods js Deployment since all my servers are very old (any alternatives.)

Tags: node.js, windows, deployment

All the servers which i have are windows servers which are very old.
What would be an alternate to deploy the Node js tool which i have developed.
Any free servers on-line or from Local,is it possible to make it available to everyone.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When you are developing it's typical to run your Node apps locally on your own computer and use localhost to connect to them. But to make it available to the wider public then you really need to get a server. The cheapest options are Virtual Private Servers. The only free option to have such a server that I know about is Digital Ocean when you register with a [coupon link](https://m.do.co/c/64b6b577b3de) to get 10 usd coupon to use on their servers, which is two months for their cheapest server - which is actually quite nice: 512MB RAM, 20GB SSD disk, and 1000GB monthly transfer. The billing is actually per hour so if you want a server just once in a while for some tests, that 10 usd credit can potentially last you for years. There are no limits on domains that you host and you can choose an operating system from: [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/), [Debian](https://www.debian.org/), [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/), [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/), [CentOS](https://www.centos.org/), [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/). You can choose location in New York, San Francisco, Toronto, London, Frankfurt, Singapore, Bangalore and Amsterdam - whatever place is closest to you or your users.